# How to find if a substring is in single quotes or not?

Tags: javascript, string, validation

Suppose I have an array and a string:

```
let arr = ['abc', 'def', 'xyz'];
let str = "something'abc'text'def'";
```

I want find if the string includes array elements that are in single quotes.

I tried finding substring and then finding index and checking the character at those index but it's not working.

Comment: `str.includes("'abc'")` ?

Comment: Hi sapna and welcome to Stack Overflow. There's a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for new users you can take, and the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) has a lot of articles on how to benefit from the site. ["how do I ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) covers how to get responses to your questions efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

```
let arr = ['abc', 'def', 'xyz'];
let str = "something'abc'text'def'";
str.indexOf("'abc'"); // this returns 9, indicating the substring starts from index of 9
str.indexOf("'" + arr[0] + "'"); // Just example, but same with this, just need to add the ' to the string.
```

Comment: This code worked for me

`let arr = ['abc', 'def', 'xyz'];
    arr.forEach((item) => {
        if (str.includes(item)) {
            if (expression.includes(`'${item}'`)) {
                console.log("yes : ", item);
            }
        }
    });`